# How to make sublists from a list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, loops

I have a list of numbers and I want to make sublists,
where each sublist begins at 1 and ends at 3.

This is my list :

`List<String> items = [ '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '4', '3', '1', '3' ];`

This is what I want to get : `listOfLists = [[1,2,3], [1,2,4,3], [1,3]]`

Comment: This is an incomplete spec.  What if the first item is not 1?  What if there's no 3 to end a segment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A oneliner way to do it is

```
listOfLists = items.join().split(RegExp(r'(?<=3)(?=1)')).map((e) => e.split('')).toList();
```

EDIT:

I learned about `splitBetween` after my first answer. This will make it even more concise:

```
listOfLists = items.splitBetween((first, second) => first == '3' && second == '1').toList();
```

This does require the `collection` package so you also need to do

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

Comment: btw, there are also `splitBefore` and `splitAfter` methods (could be handy in some cases too)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your list like this:

```
void main() {
  List<String> items = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '4', '3', '1', '3'];
  List<List<String>> listOfLists = [];

  int? startIndex;
  int? endIndex;

  for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    final item = items[i];

    if (item == '1') {
      if (startIndex != null && endIndex != null) {
        listOfLists.add(items.sublist(startIndex, endIndex + 1));
      }
      startIndex = i;
      endIndex = null;
    } else if (item == '3') {
      endIndex = i;
    }
  }

  // Add the last sublist if it ends with '3'
  if (startIndex != null && endIndex != null) {
    listOfLists.add(items.sublist(startIndex, endIndex + 1));
  }

  print(listOfLists);
}
```

You initialize `listOfLists` to store the sublists.
Iterating through the original list items:
When you encounter '1', you set the `startIndex` to the current index.
When you encounter '3', you set the `endIndex` to the current index.
If you find '1' again before finding '3', it means a new sublist has started, so you add the previous sublist to `listOfLists`.
In the end you add the last sublist if it ends with '3'.

Answer (score 1):

I added a couple of tests based on guesses:

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final items = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '4', '3', '1', '3'];
  var accum = <String>[];
  final result = <List<String>>[];
  for (final item in items) {
    print(item);
    switch (item) {
      case '1':
        if (accum.isNotEmpty) {
          throw Exception('accum is not empty $accum but saw 1');
        }
        accum.add(item);

      case '3':
        if (accum.isEmpty) {
          throw Exception('accum is empty but saw 3');
        }
        accum.add(item);
        result.add(accum);
        accum = [];
      default:
        if (accum.isEmpty) {
          throw Exception('accum is empty but saw $item, not 1');
        }
        accum.add(item);
    }
  }
  if (accum.isNotEmpty) {
    throw Exception('accum is not empty but saw $accum');
  }
  print(result);
}
```

Comment: `splitBetween` to the rescue! only two test should be added if the first item is 1 and the last is 3: `final input = ['1','2','3','1','2','4','3','1','3'];
/* needs: import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; */
final output = input.splitBetween((first, second) => first == '3' && second == '1').toList();
print('$input => $output');`

Comment: That doesn't report an error if the list is improperly organized like my code does.

Comment: so the test callback to `splitBetween` needs to be extended a bit... (3,1) ok (3,?) error (?,1) error -

Comment: That won't cover the case when the first item is not 1 or the last item is not 3, unless splitBetween is also called at the edges as a no-op but only for validation.

Comment: yes, it will: `bool test(int i, String first, String second) => switch ((first, second)) {
('3', '1') => true,
('3', _) || (_, '1') => throw 'error at position $i: ($first, $second)',
(_, _) => false,
};` and call it `input.splitBetweenIndexed(test);`

Comment: however it will not cover the case when the first item is 3 or last is 1 :-( but I am not sure if it is what OP wants...

Comment: Yes, my comment on the OP question raised that issue, and I had to commit to something for my code.  I kept the narrowest possible definition.